# Updating NService Bus from 1.9 to 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I currently implemented NService 1.9 in one of my project. I want to update the project from NServicebus 1.9 to NServiceBus 2.0. 
Will there be any major changes that I need to do.. or Only configuration changes are fine?

Can anybody help on this, provide me any links containing about this information?

nRk

Answer (score 0):

The major thing that we had to deal with is moving to the Generic Host.  You can stick with hosting NSB on your own, but the GH brings some nice things like the concept of Profiles.  This was a really simple upgrade and you can ditch your custom host.  The other change we noticed was in the logging area.  There are two places to handle configuration of this, part of it is in the config file and part of it is via code.  Other than that, there wasn't much to change as the guys did a good job of backwards compat.